# My question couldn't be submitted because of an 'error above'. Which error above?

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Am I missing something here? I can't submit my question and I don't know why.

[image]

Which error above??!!

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but I forget. I can say, however, that it was either Chrome or Edge, which is based in Chrome.

Comment: Guess I could have looked in the dev console

Comment: Was there a blocked pop-up?

Comment: Not that I saw.